# Как вывести миниаютюру записи в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю запрос в бд, и при выводе обнаружил проблему. Что данные об изображении нигде не находятся, тобишь в админке я ее задаю "миниаютюру записи" а вывести значения по средством запроса не могу.
Запрос выглядит так:

```
$latest = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY id='DESC'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Миниатюра для записи выводится на сайте не через `$wpdb`, а иначе:

```
if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() )
{
    the_post_thumbnail(array(300,225), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю проще.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

А если лень задавать каждый раз миниатюру, можно написать такую функцию:

```
function first_img(){
    global $post;preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',$post->post_content,$img);
    return $img['1'];
}
```

И выводить ее вот так:

```
<?php $img=first_img();echo $img?>
```